# How can you prove $1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4} < 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3$ by induction?

Tags: calculus, logic, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

Can you provide the steps and corresponding explanations to prove the following predicate by induction?

$$P(n) := 1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4} < 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3$$

I've done some work on it myself by attempting to show that $\frac{k^4}{4} < \frac{(k + 1)^4}{4}$ for the RHS, but I don't understand exactly what I am doing.

Thank you.

**Notice:** This is not a homework question. I'm attempting to self-study Calculus over the Summer.

Comment: You could try to show instead that $\frac{(n-1)^4}4\leq 1+\cdots +(n-1)^3\leq\frac{n^4}4$. To me, that looks easier, at least in the face of it.

Comment: Use the standard formula for the sum: $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + n^3 = n^2(n+1)^2/4$. Prove that formula by induction.

Comment: @Arthur Could you show how to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

By induction we have

- Base case: $n=1\implies 0<\frac14<1$
- Induction step, we assume true

$$P(n) := 1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3 < \frac{n^4}{4} < 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3$$

and we need to prove

$$P(n+1) := 1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3+n^3 < \frac{(n+1)^4}{4} < 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3+(n+1)^3$$

then we have

$$1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3+n^3 < n^3 +\frac{n^4}{4}$$

$$\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3< 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3+(n+1)^3$$

then it suffices to prove that

$$n^3 +\frac{n^4}{4}< \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}<\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3$$

that is

$$n^3 < \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}-\frac{n^4}{4}<(n+1)^3$$

Comment: Thank you. But how does the difference between both predicates actually help me? I'm stuck with these kinds of problems because I can't attain the intuition to solve them.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I've added some detail for the derivation, we need simply to prove that $$n^3 < \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}-\frac{n^4}{4}<(n+1)^3$$

Comment: Thank you. So, on the first step, when you add $n^3$ to both sides, is that equivalent to going to the $(n + 1)$-th sum? Also, what is the last part of the second to last step when you use $\frac{n^4}{4} + (n+1)^3$?

Comment: In other words, how do you come up with the whole inequality in the second to the last step?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill We need to prove P(n+1) then bu P(N) we have for the LHS $$1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3+n^3 < n^3 +\frac{n^4}{4}$$ and for the RHS $$\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3< 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3+(n+1)^3$$

Comment: @JamieCorkhill therefore if we show that $$n^3 +\frac{n^4}{4}< \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}<\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3$$ we have proved P(n+1).

Comment: Thank you. Everything makes sense except one thing. Why do you put the $\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$ in the middle? Does it come from $P(n+1)$?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill What we want to prove is that $$1^3 + 2^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3+n^3 < n^3 +\frac{n^4}{4}< \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}<\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3< 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3+(n+1)^3$$ which implies that $P(n+1)$ is true.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to ask you, when we prove by induction and attempt to go to $(n+1)$, do we plug it in for $n$ on the LHS such that $((n+1)-1)^3 = n^3$, and that is why you add $n^3$ to both sides? And then on the LHS, you plug $(n+1)$ into the $n^3$, and thus end up adding $(n+1)^3$ to both sides?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For the left hand side inequality we have
$$ 1^3 + 2^3 +\ldots +n^3 < \frac{n^4}4 + n^3 < \frac{n^4}4 + \frac14 (4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1) = \frac{(n+1)^4}{4} $$

Comment: Thank you. Do you create the 1/4 and the polynomial because you know it will factor into $(n+1)^4$?

Comment: Yes, that was the goal.

Comment: But how are you allowed to do that since you are not adding to both sides of the inequality?

Comment: I'm just continuing the inequality. As in $1 < 2 < 2 +1 = 3$.

Comment: In that example, you can continue the inequality because you know 1 is less than 2, which is in turn less than 1 + 2. That makes sense, but it seems that you have to know that 1 is less than 2 first. In my case, we assume the original $P(n)$ true, but not $P(n+1)$. So how can you assume the LHS of the inequality is true to add the polynomial to the RHS?

Comment: The first inequality is $P(n)$ with $n^3$ added to each side.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a generalization.

$P(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{m-1} < \frac{n^{m}}{m} < \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m-1}
$

Base case.

For $n=1$
this is
$0 < \frac1{m} < 1
$
which is true.

Induction step.

Suppose true for $n$.

$P(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{m-1} < \frac{n^{m}}{m} < \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m-1}
$

Want to show that
$P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.

First, the left inequality of $P(n+1)$,
which is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m-1} < \frac{(n+1)^{m}}{m}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{m-1}+n^{m-1}\\
&<\frac{n^m}{m}+n^{m-1}\\
&=\frac{n^{m}+mn^{m-1}}{m}\\
\end{array}
$

so we are done if
$n^m+mn^{m-1}
\lt (n+1)^m
$
or,
dividing by $n^m$,
$1+m/n
\lt (1+1/n)^m
$
and this follows from
Bernoulli's inequality.

Next, the right inequality of $P(n+1)$,
which is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^{m-1} > \frac{(n+1)^{m}}{m}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^{m-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m-1}+(n+1)^{m-1}\\
&>\frac{n^m}{m}+(n+1)^{m-1}\\
\end{array}
$

so we are done if
$\frac{n^m}{m}+(n+1)^{m-1}
\ge \frac{(n+1)^m}{m}
$
or
$n^m
\ge (n+1)^m-m(n+1)^{m-1}
=(n+1)^{m-1}(n+1-m)
$.
or
$1
\ge (1+1/n)^{m-1}(1-(m-1)/n)
$
or
$(1+1/n)^{m-1}
\le \frac1{1-(m-1)/n}
$.

This requires its own proof.
which we will do
by induction on $m$.

For $m=1$
this is
$1
\le 1$
which is true.

Suppose it is true for $m$
where $m < n-1$.
Then
$(1+1/n)^{m}
=(1+1/n)^{m-1}(1+1/n)
\le \frac1{1-(m-1)/n}(1+1/n)
$.
We want 
$\frac1{1-(m-1)/n}(1+1/n)
\le \frac1{1-m/n}
$
or
$(1-m/n)(1+1/n)
\le 1-(m-1)/n
$
or
$1-(m-1)/n
\ge 1-(m-1)/n+m/n^2
$
which is true.

Therefore,
if $m < n-1$,
or $n > m+1$,
the right side is true.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment from above, I'm setting out to prove that
$$
\frac{(n-1)^4}4\leq 1+\cdots +(n-1)^3\leq\frac{n^4}4
$$
for suitable $n$ (say $n\geq 1$). (I feel that this ought to be easier as I only have one long sum of cubes to contend with rather than two.)

The base case is easily shown: $0\leq 0\leq \frac14$.

As for the induction step, assume $k\geq 1$ and that
$$
\frac{(k-1)^4}4\leq 1+\cdots +(k-1)^3\leq\frac{k^4}4
$$
Adding $k^3$ to all sides, we get
$$
\frac{(k-1)^4 + 4k^3}4\leq 1+\cdots +(k-1)^3 + k^3\leq\frac{k^4+4k^3}4
$$
Now in the numerator on the right-hand side we have
$$
k^4 + 4k^3\leq k^4 + 4k^3+6k^2+4k+1 = (k+1)^4
$$
and on the left-hand side we have
$$
(k-1)^4 + 4k^3 = k^4 + 6k^2-4k+1 = k^4 + 1 + 2k(3k-2)\geq k^4
$$
(where that last inequality is true because both $1$ and $2k(3k-2)$ are positive).

Gathering it all up, this yields
$$
\frac{k^4}4\leq \frac{(k-1)^4 + 4k^3}4\leq 1+\cdots +(k-1)^3 + k^3\leq\frac{k^4+4k^3}4\leq \frac{(k+1)^4}4
$$
and this finishes the induction step.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why you use $(n-1)$ and not $(n+1)$?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill So that what I add to all sides in the induction step (in order to get the next sum of cubes) is $k^3$, and so that both the left-hand side and the right-hand side at some point is $k^4/4$. If I used $n$ instead, then the right-hand side would've started at $(k+1)^4/4$ and gone up to $(k+2)^4/4$ during the course of the proof, and I would have had to add $(k+1)^3$ to all sides. It just makes the algebra easier this way.

Comment: So because you subtracted one from all sides, the value of the inequality never changed and you can prove it that way instead?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill What this entire thing is about is a long inequality chain like this: $$\cdots\leq \frac{(n-1)^4}4\leq 1+\cdots + (n-1)^3\leq\frac{n^4}4\leq 1+\cdots +n^3\leq \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}\leq \cdots$$I didn't subtract $1$ from all sides. Instead, I started my proof at an earlier point in the chain. (Your original statement was terms $2, 3, 4$ in this chain, I'm proving terms $1, 2, 3$; either one allows us to link the entire chain together.) But yes, mathematically it doesn't matter. Mentally it does.